# JQuery/Javascript - How to change <label> based on its corresponding <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, laravel

I want to change a label if its corresponding dropdown has changed value (In the same row). this is the html page.

[image]

Each dropdown and label has different ids. For example if there is 4 dropdowns then their ids will be dropdown1, dropdown2, dropdown 3, dropdown 4. same with label. But my problem is I don't know how to correspond or chain the two elements together, for example: dropdown 1 should be connected to label 1, meaning whenever the select1 dropdown has changed the label1 will change (by displaying the dropdown1's current selected option).

**Here's my snippet source code for HTML:**

```
<td> 
    <select class="form-control" id = "bookingTypeDropDown{{$counter1}}"> <!-- Assigning of unique ids based on iteration number -->
           @foreach($booking_types as $booking_type)
                <option value = "{{$booking_type->book_type_price}}">
                     {{$booking_type->book_type_name}}
                </option>
           @endforeach
    </select>
</td>
@foreach($depart_destination_country as $destination)
    <td>
        <input type="radio" 
               name="departure_flight_id" 
               value="{{$flight->flight_id}}" required>
         <label id = "calculatedFare{{$counter1}}">price here</label> <!-- Assigning of unique ids based on iteration number -->

         <input type="hidden" name="total_departure_fare" value="#" required>   
    </td>
@endforeach
```

**This picture below is the html for the snippet source code provided above:**

[image]

**Source code (Responsible for the changing of label when select was changed):**

```
<script type = "application/javascript">

window.onload = function() {

    var numItems = $('.form-control').length; //Counts the number of <select> by class
    var dropdowns =[];
    var labels = [];

    for(var i=0; i<numItems; i++) //Iteration for getting all <select> and <labels> and storing them in their respective arrays
    {
        dropdowns[i] = document.getElementById("bookingTypeDropDown" + i);
        labels[i] = document.getElementById("calculatedFare" + i);
    }

    var currentElement; 

    for(var d=0; d<dropdowns.length; d++)
    {
        var price;

        $(dropdowns[d]).change(function (){ //if dropdown object changed option
            var price = $(this).val(); //getting of option's value
            currentElement = d; //getting of array index where change was detected
            console.log(price);             //printing only
            console.log(currentElement);    //printing of what index does the changed occured
        });

        $(labels[currentElement]).text("PHP " + price); //
    }

}
```

The problem in my javascript code is that it always print the last index or iteration number (which is 4 in this scenario) but the values being printed are right. for example if I clicked the first dropdown it prints the right value but not the right index (prints index 4 instead of index 1). No problem on value.

What I want is the right detection of  element that has been changed option and once it has been detected it should change its corresponding label.

**Scenario example:**

Select1 = Label1
Select2 = Label2
Select3 = Label3
....

**How do i coordiante a select to a label?**

Comment: "*how to correspond or chain the two elements together*" - give them the same data-  (eg "pair") attribute+value then in the `select` change, it's: `$("[data-pair='" + $(this).data("pair") +  "']").text($(this).val())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do it by using selectors and classes, you don't have to setup and enumerate through nested IDs.

Please run the below code snippet.

```js
$(() => {

  $('.select-price').on('change', function() {
    onChange(this);
  });
  
  function onChange(selectEl) {
    const $row = $(selectEl).parents('tr');
    const $label = $('td:eq(1) label', $row);
    const $departure_flight_input = $('td:eq(1) input[name="departure_flight_id"]', $row);
    
    $label.text($(selectEl).val());
    $departure_flight_input.val($(selectEl).val());
  }
  
  function getInitialPrice() {
    $('.select-price').each((index, el) => onChange(el));
  }
  
  getInitialPrice();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control select-price">
        <option value="1.00">1.00</option>
        <option value="2.00">2.00</option>
        <option value="3.00">3.00</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="departure_flight_id" value="" required>
      <label>price here</label> 
    </td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <select class="form-control select-price">
        <option value="1.10">1.10</option>
        <option value="2.20">2.20</option>
        <option value="3.30">3.30</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td>
      <input type="radio" name="departure_flight_id" value="" required>
      <label>price here</label> 
    </td>
  <tr>
</table>
```

Comment: it is working but it seems it cannot find the label object when I applied it into my web app

Comment: already fixed it just by chaging the index from 1 to 7 because the label is in the table cell no. 7 of every table row. From td:eq(1) to td:eq(7)... thanks!